# opening bootstrap-combobox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Daniel Farrell's bootstrap Combobox

https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

I want to make the select box open when the user clicks the textbox, (and then if they type in the textbox it filters as usual)

I have tried to add some extra code on the constructor:

```
 var Combobox = function (element, options) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.combobox.defaults, options);
    this.$source = $(element);
    this.$container = this.setup();
    this.$element = this.$container.find('input[type=text]');
    this.$target = this.$container.find('input[type=hidden]');
    this.$button = this.$container.find('.dropdown-toggle');
    this.$menu = $(this.options.menu).appendTo('body');
    this.template = this.options.template || this.template
    this.matcher = this.options.matcher || this.matcher;
    this.sorter = this.options.sorter || this.sorter;
    this.highlighter = this.options.highlighter || this.highlighter;
    this.shown = false;
    this.selected = false;
    this.refresh();
    this.transferAttributes();
    this.listen();
    if (options.opener!= undefined) {
        this.opener(options.opener); //my extra "option"

    }
  };


Combobox.prototype = {
  opener: function (element) {
      $(element).click(function () {
      //What to write here
   }
 }
```

but I cant seem to get the right commands to open the select options when I click into the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "your textare id" with your textarea selector and "your select drop down" with your select dropdown selector and check

```
$('your textare id').on('click',function(){
     $('your select drop down').siblings('.combobox-container').find('.add-on.btn').trigger('click');    
}).on('keyup', function(){
     $('.combobox-container .combobox.input-large').val($(this).val()).trigger('change')
});
```